# Tolfdir won't cast the spell at me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I have the cheat room mod on Xbox One, and I am using it for the first time. I had added all spells beforehand and it wouldn't work so I removed them and learned the ward spell from Tolfdir, but it still won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a known bug in all versions of the game on all platforms

***"When teaching the Lesser Ward spell, Tolfdir may not shoot fire at the Dragonborn."***

Try reloading a previous save before you got the "First Lessons" quest.

Or try the console command to mark the quest as complete:
`SetObjectiveCompleted <MG01> <1>`

---

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Tolfdir